# SQL - Ordering/Limiting Related Information From Different Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I am running across an interesting problem and I wasn't quite sure how to tackle it - hence here we go.

Let's say I have a **Table A: LISTINGS** and a **Table B: Products**. Listings and Products are two separate tables with entirely different columns, and come with their own joins to pull related information to them.

The similarity is that both tables have a price column but maintains this information under different column names. ***What I want to do is pull back an n amount of least expensive prices from the combined dataset of the two tables.***

Given the fact that the joins for the two different tables are ultimately very different, I started out by writing two different SELECT statements. I then ordered the prices ASC for each table, combined the results of the two queries, and sorted the resultant array by price again.

The inherent flaw here of course is that the datasets from each SELECT statement are unique to their own pool of data. In short, the resulting rank of prices from each SELECT will only be true for that particular dataset, but not when compared to the combined results of both tables in their entirety. This issue is magnified when you make multiple requests to the datasets to fetch back paginated rows.

Given the limitations of using two separate queries, I think the only solution is to write the query as one SELECT so that the dataset remains the same regardless of using LIMIT or querying the database for more data. I am stumped on how to write a single query that gathers data from two entirely different tables (*all whilst joining each table on many other tables*) and comparing them across one column in the same SELECT statement.

*Ideally what would happen would be the following:*

**TABLE A : LISTINGS**

- ROW 1 - Listing 1 - $50
- ROW 2 - Listing 2 - $20
- ROW 3 - Listing 3 - $40

**TABLE B - PRODUCTS**

- ROW 1 - Item 1 - $100
- ROW 2 - Item 2 - $300
- ROW 3 - Item 3 - $55
- ROW 4 - Item 4 - $1000

The first call for the two cheapest prices would only pull back ***Row 2 and Row 3 from Table A***.

The next call to pull back the next two cheapest prices would pull ***Row 1 from Table A and Row 3 from Table B***.

The next call would pull ***Row 2 and Row 1 from Table B***.

Finally, the last call would pull ***Row 4 from Table B*** and inform the user that there are no more results to be pulled back between the two tables.

Let me know if any of this needs more clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for the `UNION` operator.  You might end up writing queries something like this:

```
SELECT
  name,
  price
FROM (
  SELECT 
    listings.name AS name,
    listings.price AS price
  FROM
    listings
    [JOIN ...]
  [WHERE ...]
  ORDER BY
    price
  LIMIT 2

  UNION ALL

  SELECT 
    products.name AS name,
    products.price AS price
  FROM
    products
    [JOIN ...]
  [WHERE ...]
  ORDER BY
    price
  LIMIT 2
)
ORDER BY price
LIMIT 2
```

Comment: Thanks John! Just got around to validating this. This is exactly what I needed - for others who run across this table, I made an edit on the code to include setting each table as an alias. Otherwise you get an SQL error. Hope this ends up helping someone down the line :)